# Grease Pencil animation rendering only the background

Tags: rendering, animation, grease-pencil

I need to render an animation where the PNG files from the rendering will be saved. I'm using the demo file that is provided by Blender (https://download.blender.org/demo/test/ForYou.blend) - Grease Pencil Automation (ForYou.blend).

The problem is that when i'm running the animation rendering it creates the PNG files with the background only and the animation objects are not captured (same goes to a case where i create video file).

Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In order to render a grease pencil animation, you have to use OpenGL render.  Using the blend file that you provided, if you open it, up there are two views, 
directly under the view that you want to render there is a plus
[image]

If you click that and then scroll to the right by dragging the middle mouse over the bottom section(the panel menu) you will see the OpenGL render button.

[image]

The one on the left renders the current frame and the one on the right renders the animation.  Just make sure that you deselect everything before you render as it is just rendering the viewport at a higher resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes, i've already tried it and it works. Just wanted to understand if the inability to render the active scene (not the OpenGL way) is the limitation of this specific animation?

Comment: I'm not an expert but as far as I'm aware thats the only way grease pencil animations can be rendered

Comment: Thanks Ben. Will have to find some other animation then :)

Comment: Blender offers demo files here that can be used as benchmarks https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/.  They have the splash screen ones, some cycles tests, and even some real-time ones.